# apache2 site shows on www.example.com only, default apache2 page for http://example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

My site www.wraithnath.com works correctly when visiting from http://www.wraithnath.com

but when i visit from http://wraithnath.com i get the default apache 2 page.

some of the images in the site no longer work that are referenced from http://wraithnath.com

this was all working before so i dont know what has changed.

my DNS has an a record pointing to @ to the IP address and there is a cname for www.

my conf looks like this:

```
ServerAdmin *removed*
DocumentRoot /var/www/WraithNath
ServerName wraithnath.com
ServerAlias www.wraithnath.com

    <Directory /var/www/WraithNath/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

what else can i check to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to .htaccess and do the redirect to www without the need of 2 vhost

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wraithnath.com
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.wraithnath.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just gave this a go but that didnt seem to work for me, i still get the apache2 default page when typeing wraithnath.com into google chrome (I put this code in the .htaccess file in the root of www)

Comment: @WraithNath try to disable the default website...000-default and reload Apache.

Comment: Thanks! that did it, I can only assume at some point i must have run a2ensite on the default configuration by accident!

Comment: No problem. Have a great day!

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this in future, it was disabling the 000-default.conf that did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www
Use a virutal host like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 # Set domain to redirect to www
 ServerName wraithnath.com
 Redirect permanent / http://www.wraithnath.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VritualHost *:80>
 # Add directory to this virtual host
 ServerName www.wraithnath.com
 <Directory /var/www/WraithNath/>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This usually happens when apache is not configured to serve from a domain. (Check your spelling!)

Comment: Thanks, I just gave this a go but that didnt seem to work for me, i still get the apache2 default page when typeing wraithnath.com into google chrome

Comment: Accidentally put ServerAlias instead of ServerName on the virtual hosts. As long as you don't have any other virtual hosts listening on port 80 this will work. (Just tested it under Apache/2.2.15)

Comment: thanks ticoombs, I have got it working now based on Andys comment, I think i had run a2ensite on the default config files so it was serving those in preference, I ran a2disssite on both default configs and it fixed it.